# I am loading text into R for Text mining, and getting "â€™" instead of "'" (apostrophe)

Tags: r, rstudio, text-mining

When loading the text into R, the apostrophe is getting converted into "â€™"
for example:

```
I'm => Iâ€™m
We're => Weâ€™re
you're => youâ€™re
```

I have tried to replace the incorrect sequence, but nothing changes.

```
for (j in seq(Docs))
{
Docs[[j]] <- gsub("â€™", "'", Docs[[j]])
}
```

Can you help out.
What settings need i change in RStudio or command should i use to properly load the text files.

Comment: How did you "load" your text into R? Try changing encoding (see `Encoding()`) from to UTF-8. In order to do so look at `iconv`.

Comment: The text files are present in a folder called "folder". i use the following command to create a corpus.    `Docs = Corpus(DirSource(folder))`

Comment: The weird thing is that in some places the apostrophe is coming correctly, and in some places the faulty sequence is coming. it's all from the same text file!! :(

Comment: Try using this `Encoding(Docs)  <- "UTF-8"`. It can be used just before converting the text to a corpus.

Comment: I am using .txt files, stored in a folder called "folder"
`folder = file.path("C:/Projects/6 Text mining/Texts")`

Comment: just to make things as clear as possible, i added some extra options..`Docs = VCorpus(DirSource(folder), readerControl=list(reader=readPlain,
                                                     list(language="en",
                                                     Encoding("UTF-8"))))`. There is still no change!! those weird characters still come